# jQuery Draggable Clearing Metadata

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, drag-and-drop

I'm implementing the jQuery draggable plugin as well as the metadata plugin but am struggling with accessing the metadata from the callback function of the droppable. I can access the metadata outside of the draggable / droppable functions and it works fine; but when I call from within the function I get an empty object - unless I pre-load the metadata. Let me explain further... I have the following:

```
<div id="NavigationSorting">
<ul class="drgLocation">
    <li>
    <span>Location 1</span>
        <ul class="drgArea">
            <li data="{JobAreaID: '1'}">
            <div class="dzArea ui-droppable"></div>
            <span>Area 1</span>
                <ul class="drgTreatment">
                    <li><span>Treatment 1.1</span></li>
                    <li><span>Treatment 1.2</span></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li data="{JobAreaID: '2'}" id="test">
            <div class="dzArea ui-droppable"></div>
            <span>Area 2</span>
                <ul class="drgTreatment">
                    <li><span>Treatment 2.1</span></li>
                    <li><span>Treatment 2.2</span></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I have the following in a document.ready block:

```
        $('#NavigationSorting .dzArea').droppable({
        accept: '.drgArea li',
        tolerance: 'touch',
        hoverClass: 'droppableArea',
        drop: function (e, ui) {
            var ul = $(this).parent();

            var data2 = $(ui.draggable).metadata({ type: 'attr', name: 'data' });
            alert(data2.JobAreaID);

            ul.before(ui.draggable);
        }
    });

    $('#NavigationSorting .drgArea>li').draggable({
        //handle: ' > dl',
        opacity: .8,
        addClasses: false,
        helper: 'clone',
        zIndex: 100
    });
```

If I drag the 2nd LI up, I get an empty object for the data (JobAreaID is undefined). However, if I add the following *before* the draggable / droppable code it works:

```
var data = $("#test").metadata({ type: 'attr', name: 'data' });
```

This is fine in my test scenario, but in production I won't know all the id values (not to mention this seems like a waste). I considered adding a class and using that in the metadata selector but it only grabs the data from the first matching element so in this case JobAreaID 2 would be null.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as this is driving me crazy but I can't believe it's not possible.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe the attribute name `data` is messing up between the two plugins. Have you tried another identifier or use something like `data-xxx` ? Also, you don't need to do `$(ui.draggable)` as ui.draggable is already a jquery object.

Comment: Good thought about the attribute name but that isn't it. I tried your suggestion and it still didn't work. I came up with another solution that will work though. Even though metadata only supports the first element, I simply call that in a loop like so: `$("#NavigationSorting .drgArea>li").each(function (i) {
 $(this).metadata({ type: 'attr', name: 'data' });
});`

Answer (score 0):

I still don't think it's the best approach, but I solved this by looping through all my data-containing elements and populating the metadata individually like so:

```
$("#NavigationSorting .drgArea>li").each(function (i) {
    $(this).metadata({ type: 'attr', name: 'data' });
});
```

I do this on page load, and then I can access it no problem from the droppable function.